# Xamarin.Forms, XAML and XMLNS issue

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding

I have an issue with xlmns and x:Static binding.

My 'Test.Constants' static class definition

```
namespace Test
{
  static class Constants
  {
     static public int TXT_SIZE=46;
     static public Color TXT_COLOR=Color.Red;
  }
}
```

My XAML:

```
(snip)
xmlns:ctes="clr-namespace:Test;assembly=Test"
(snip)
<Label x:Name="lblTest" FontSize="{x:Static ctes:Constants.TXT_SIZE}" TextColor="{x:Static ctes:Constants.TXT_COLOR}" />
(snip)
```

My goal is to bind Constants.TXT_SIZE from my constants class, thus having everything in XAML.

i can do, in CSharp:

```
lblTest.FontSize=Constants.TXT_SIZE;
```

i can do, in XAML:

```
TextColor="{x:Static ctes:Constants.TXT_COLOR}"
```

or, in XAML:

```
FontSize="46"
```

but i *can't* write, and i don't understand why:

```
FontSize="{x:Static ctes:Constants.TXT_SIZE}"
```

It throws an error:

> XFC0009    No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "FontSize", or mismatching type between value and property.

I changed my constant type to string instead of int but same error.

Any idea why ?

Comment: The type of `FontSize` is double:).

Comment: i feel totally stupid. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of FontSize is double.
If you change TXT_SIZE to double it should work.